# Doxygen with *.in file

Tags: c++, documentation, doxygen

I generate functions with *.in files

```
   class Foo
   {
   public:
   ...

      #define FUNCTION(returnType, getterName) \
         returnType getterName(uint8_t iValue) const;
      #include "Functions.in"
      #undef FUNCTION

   ...
   };
```

and want to use Doxygen. The Doxygen configuration looks like:

```
...
INPUT                  = Path/To/Foo
...
FILE_PATTERNS          = *.in \
                         *.c \
                         *.cc \
                         *.cxx \
                         *.cpp \
                         *.c++ 
...
SEARCH_INCLUDES        = YES
...
INCLUDE_PATH           = Path/To/Foo
...
```

I can see the *.in files in the documentation but not the functions in the class. Additionally Doxygen creates following warning

```
Foo.h:10: warning: include file Functions.in not found, perhaps you forgot to add its directory to INCLUDE_PATH?
```

Does somebody know how to use Doxygen with *.in files? Is actually possible to use Doxygen with generated-code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read [the Doxygen preprocessing documentation](https://www.star.bnl.gov/public/comp/sofi/doxygen/preprocessing.html) you will see that

> Source files that are used as input to doxygen can be parsed by doxygen's built-in C-preprocessor.

And

> By default doxygen does only partial preprocessing. That is, it evaluates conditional compilation statements (like #if) and evaluates macro definitions, but it does not perform macro expansion.

This default behavior can be changed:

> In case you want to expand the CONST_STRING macro, you should set the [MACRO_EXPANSION](https://www.star.bnl.gov/public/comp/sofi/doxygen/config.html#cfg_macro_expansion) tag in the config file to `YES`.

So the solution is to *not* run the `*.in` files through Doxygen, but instead set the `MACRO_EXPANSION` configuration variable to `YES`, and the macros will be fully expanded and their expansions should be parsed.

Comment: Another problem might be that the `*.in` files are not recognized properly and should be made know to doxygen by telling that it are C files, see `EXTENSION_MAPPING`

Comment: Thanks for the help!